# Apenas o primeiro checkbox é setado de uma listview clicando em qualquer lugar do item

Tags: android

bom dia. Sou novato no forum e iniciante em android. Criei uma ListView através de um Base Adapter, com checkbox selecionável, até ai tudo bem. Mas quando clico em qualquer lugar de algum item, apenas o checkbox do primeiro item é setado. Como na imagem, cliquei em algum lugar do segundo item e o checkbox do primeiro foi setado. Clicando apenas nos checkbox eles são setados normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já procurei no forum mas não encontrei uma solução. Se tiver desculpe pela duplicata. Por favor, como posso resolver esse problema? O meu getView do meu adapter.

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_selected, null);
    }

    ImageView icone = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView nome = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTextViewItemListNomeSelected);
    TextView fone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTextViewItemListFoneSelected);
    CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myCheckBoxItemListSelected);

    Contato contato = contactList.get(position);

    icone.setImageResource(contato.getImage());
    nome.setText(contato.getNome());
    fone.setText(contato.getTel());
    cbx.setChecked(contato.isCheck());

    cbx.setTag(contato);

    cbx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CheckBox check = (CheckBox)v;
            Contato ct = (Contato)v.getTag();
            ct.setCheck(((CheckBox)v).isChecked());

            if(check.isChecked()){
                if(! idSelecteds.contains(ct.getID())){
                    idSelecteds.add(ct.getID());
                }
            }else {
                if(idSelecteds.contains(ct.getID())){
                    idSelecteds.remove(ct.getID());
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

A implementação da meu OnItemClickListener realizei dessa maneira.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.myCheckBoxItemListSelected);
    cb.setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que dentro do `OnItemClickListener`, esta chamando o método `findViewById` da `Activity`.

O `findViewById` transversa todas as `Views` a partir da raiz, retornando a **primeira encontrada**. Logo a primeira é a `Checkbox` da primeira linha.

Você precisa executar o `findViewById` na `View` que é passada por parâmetro no método `onItemClick`, é a `View` que representa a linha do `ListView` retornada pelo `Adapter`.

Comment: Wakim, muito obrigado. Problema resolvido.                        </br>public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
   long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  CheckBox check = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.myCheckBoxItemListSelected);
  check.setChecked(true);
 }